# How to make a phone call by clicking on a label?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

How to make a phone call in Xamarin Forms by clicking on a label? I know this question is cliche because someone already asked it here,

[How to make a phone call in Xamarin.Forms by clicking on a label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551576/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-xamarin-forms-by-clicking-on-a-label)

I can't ask in that post because it requires 50 reputation to comment. But I still need to know the answer because that post didn't show the final code. So here's my code,

RequestorPage.xaml

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="10,0,10,0">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Start">
          <Image Source="detail_mobile" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" />
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center">
          <Label FontSize="Small" Text="{Binding RequestorHp}" x:Name="reqHp" />
      </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

RequestorPage.xaml.cs

```
public RequestorPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                // handle the tap
                var phoneDialer = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;
                if (phoneDialer.CanMakePhoneCall)
                {
                    phoneDialer.MakePhoneCall(reqHp.Text);
                }
            };

            // attache the gesture to your label
            reqHp.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
        }
```

When I run in the simulator, error appears when I click RequestorHp label. Here's the error,

> System.NotImplementedException has been thrown
>
> This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this
>   assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main
>   application project in order to reference the platform-specific
>   implementation.

Which part did I miss? Please help me. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [dependency service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to run the `MakePhoneCall()` method inside the iOS and Android Projects from your shared project.

In your Xamarin.Forms Project, you can add the following code to make the call to the dependency service:

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.Android:
        DependencyService.Get<IAndroidMethods>().startPhoneCall();
        break;
    case Device.iOS:
        DependencyService.Get<IAppleMethods>().startPhoneCall();
        break;
}
```

Next, in your Xamarin.Forms project, create two interfaces: `IAppleMethods` and `IAndroidMethods` that contain the `startPhoneCall()` method.

I'll show the implementation for `IAndroidMethods`:

```
public interface IAndroidMethods
{
    void startPhoneCall(string number);
}
```

Then, in your iOS and Android projects, create classes that implement the interfaces you just created.  This would be your android class:

```
//add appropriate using declarations
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidMethods))]
namespace <YourApp>.Droid
{
    public class AndroidMethods : IAndroidMethods
    {
        public void startPhoneCall(string number)
        {
            var phoneDialer = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;
            if (phoneDialer.CanMakePhoneCall)
            {
                phoneDialer.MakePhoneCall(number);
            }
        }
    }
}
```