# NotlmplementedException in Xamarin.Forms (PCL) project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, notimplementedexception

I'm programming in Xamarin.Forms (PCL), and I have seen many post but none one works for me. I'm using the plugin **PhoneCall.Forms.Plugin** 
I made a method to call with a button that contains the next code

```
try
{
    var PhoneCallTask = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;
    if (PhoneCallTask.CanMakePhoneCall)
    {
        PhoneCallTask.MakePhoneCall("+528331607211", "Laura");
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayAlert("Llamada", "No se puede hacer llamada", "Ok");
    }
}
```

It throws an error:

> System.NotlmplementedException: This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.

[image: Deploy stops]

Comment: you have to install the package in your application (iOS/android) projects along with the PCL project.

Comment: The same package is installed in both projects

Comment: Can you add a link to the plugin you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Messaging](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins) plugin?
Like said by Jason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37551969/6391134).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`Device.OpenUri(new Uri("tel:528331607211"));`

Comment: on iOS the Uri has the format: telprompt://528331607211

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [this plugin](https://github.com/IshamMohamed/PhoneCall.Forms.Plugin) (I'm not sure if this is the specific one you're using or not), then you need to make the phone call using a Dependency service (This is explained in the plugin readme).

Make a method in your PCL project to call the dependancy service:

```
private void QCall(string number)
{
    var notificator = DependencyService.Get<IPhoneCall>();
    notificator.MakeQuickCall (number);
}
```

In each platform specific project, initialize the plugin.  For Android, this will be done in the `OnCreate` method of your `MainActivity`, and for iOS in `AppDelegate` in the `FinishedLaunching` method.  Add the following line to each after the initialization of Xamarin.Forms:

```
PhoneCallImplementation.Init();
```

Then when you call `QCall()` in your PCL project it will run the code necessary for the specific platform the user is on.